# Split string in between whole digits and section digit entities

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, replace, split

I have a file with entities in it. Where there's a whole digit entity followed by a sectioned digit entity I need to put a `</chapter>` closing element in between them.

I've tried putting it into an Array. I tried using a Regex:

```
/&Ch\d+\r\n&Ch\d+-\d+
```

Example of the text file:

```
&sc_Ch2;
&sc_Ch3;
&sc_Ch3-1;
&sc_Ch3-2;
&sc_Ch4;
&sc_Ch4-1;
&sc_Ch4-2;
&sc_Ch5;
&sc_Ch6;
&sc_Ch6-1;
&sc_Ch7;
&sc_Ch7-1;
&sc_Ch7-2;
&sc_Ch7-3;
&sc_Ch7-4;
&sc_Ch8;
```

The results would be:

```
&sc_Ch2;
&sc_Ch3;
&sc_Ch3-1;
&sc_Ch3-2;
</chapter>
&sc_Ch4;
&sc_Ch4-1;
&sc_Ch4-2;
</chapter>
&sc_Ch5;
&sc_Ch6;
&sc_Ch6-1;
</chapter>
&sc_Ch7;
&sc_Ch7-1;
&sc_Ch7-2;
&sc_Ch7-3;
&sc_Ch7-4;
</chapter>
&sc_Ch8;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So, `&sc_Ch2;`, `&sc_Ch5;` and `&sc_Ch8;` are not *chapters*. It's a *chapter* only when a string contains an hyphen and the following doesn't. So, it goes down to *there's an hyphen, start a chapter*, *there's no hyphen, it was a chapter, insert<chapter>*.

Comment: Yes they already have </chapter> enclosed in them. The last section needs the end chapter added.

Comment: It looks like, given your previous questions on this matter, that the actual structure is more complex than this. Is this the real sequence of strings you need to modify?

Comment: yes this is the exact document that needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual sequence of strings, try this: fill a `List(Of String)` with the lines representing your chapters (reading from a file or any other source).

The loop reads the list backwards, inserting the string `<chapter>` in the list when the current line contains a hyphen and the previous line didn't.

This code assumes that the chapters definition (`&sc_Ch[X];`), includes hyphens only in this specific case.

```
Dim chapters As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines("[File Path]").ToList()
Dim NotAChapter As Boolean = True

For line As Integer = chapters.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If chapters(line).Contains("-"c) Then
        If NotAChapter Then chapters.Insert(line + 1, "<chapter>")
        NotAChapter = False
    Else
        NotAChapter = True
    End If
Next

' Name the file as you please
File.WriteAllLines("chapters_new.txt", chapters)
```

Comment: I have the file being read in with Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingMasterFilePath). Would this be ok for the chapter list of string. It's not accepting it

Comment: No. Use `Dim trMasterDoc As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(existingMasterFilePath).ToList()`. If the chapters are separated in different lines as you showed in your question. Of course, `trMasterDoc` is called `chapters` in this code.

Comment: How would I put the file together again so other code can run on it? I have Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingMasterFilePath)
        Dim newMasterFileBuilder As New StringBuilder(strMasterDoc) used to manipulate the text. So I need your code to output strMasterDoc to make it work with my remaining code

Comment: See the edit and the previous comment (no `File.ReadAllText()` but `File.ReadAllLines()`, then `File.WriteAllLines()` to save it).

Comment: OK I understand and will test it. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1):

An untested theory (i ran out of time, have to go) that looks good on paper that may spark an idea

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To 8
        Dim yourText As String = "&sc_Ch2;
                                    &sc_Ch3;
                                    &sc_Ch3-1;
                                    &sc_Ch3-2;
                                    &sc_Ch4;
                                    &sc_Ch4-1;
                                    &sc_Ch4-2;
                                    &sc_Ch5;
                                    &sc_Ch6;
                                    &sc_Ch6-1;
                                    &sc_Ch7;
                                    &sc_Ch7-1;
                                    &sc_Ch7-2;
                                    &sc_Ch7-3;
                                    &sc_Ch7-4;
                                    &sc_Ch8;"
        Dim str As String = "Ch" & i
        yourText.Insert("</chapter>", yourText.LastIndexOf(str) + 2)

    Next
```

Comment: yourText would always change so I don't think this will work.

Comment: true, you would need to write to a new string

Comment: sitting in my car looking at this. i think if you declared your text at class scope this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the variation with the `-` and make use of a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a newline followed by the variant without the `-`

```
^&sc_Ch\d+-\d+;(?=(?:\r?\n|\r)&sc_Ch\d+;)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `&sc_Ch\d+-\d+;` Match `&sc_Ch`, 1+ digits, `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:\r?\n|\r)` Match newline
  - `&sc_Ch\d+;` Match `&sc_Ch`, 1+ digits, `;`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

In the replacement use the full match followed by a newline and `</chapter>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/39XxJu/1) | [vb.net demo](https://ideone.com/GoU0IX)